# SQLite ORM primary keys on multiple columns

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, orm, primary-key

What is the syntax for specifying a primary key on more than 1 column in SQLite?

I'm developing an app in C# using Xamarin and would like to use tables with a primary key on mulitple columns using SQLite ORM.

The TableObject class defines a table.
I would like to make sure the combination of ProductID and RetailerID is unique.
To accomplish this, I want to make the combination of columns the primary key.

I've tried the following:

```
class TableObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int RetailerID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The table is created like this:

```
database.CreateTable<Cache>();
```

But I get the following exception:

> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: table "TableObject" has more than one primary key

In 'default' SQLite this can be done using:

```
CREATE TABLE something (column1, column2, column3, PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2));
```

But how do I accomplish this using SQLite ORM?

Comment: If a data-first option is available, you could try a quick test DB with the schema as you suggested and create the model from the schema, in order to see what it generates in code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported as you can read here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14769/how-do-we-create-a-composite-primary-key-using-sqlite-net-orm

Some one has extended SQLite PCL to enable some additional features
https://github.com/softlion/SQLite.Net-PCL